# Applying second material on part of object

Tags: materials, objects, selection-tools

I need to make object with multiple materials, but some parts need to be "irregular" shape. I attached screenshot to explain better what I need to do. What is the best way to select part of object surface (similar to one on screenshot) so I can apply secondary material (mostly that would be some other color)

Tnx for help[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shader editor, create the first material you need. Then, duplicate the principled BSDF, and create the second material. Add a mix shader, and plug both BSDF into it.

In the factor, connect a mask texture. This is basically a black and white image telling Blender where to show each material.  It can be made with a noise texture and a color ramp. Use CTRL + SHIFT + LMB to preview a specific node. This will help you to know what your mask looks like.

This is what the node setup could look like.

[image]

Of course, for the mask, you can use any black and white image you want, meaning you can also make it by hand in the texture painting panel.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use masking in a node based material or select the faces you want to have the specific material and press "assign" on the material tab (make sure the object contain multiples material)
here is a quick tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ms89wP8m4ZU&ab_channel=Olav3DTutorials

and here a quick unpolished test showing what you can achieve:[image]

Here I used the knife tool to create the blue shape, it is not ideal as it could mess with the topology (there is a subdivision surface modifier on the object so the shape is more organic) so I would recommend using masking in node based texture.

Comment: Thank you for your help!